# Magento 2 login popup

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, login, popup

I have a client **login popup** on my page with the form

```
action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
```

How can I change this so the form **will not redirect** to the **account dashboard**?

I have **set to redirect "no"** in the backend. Does not help.

Thank you.

Edit after Prince answer:

My problem is that I do not know where to start. I have found something in

```
/home/admin/domains/qvicktime.eu/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Ajax/Login.php
```

It might control the login?

And this code?

```
            if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectRoute) {
            $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($redirectRoute);
            $this->getAccountRedirect()->clearRedirectCookie();
        }
```

But if I want to stay on the same page after login (the user should have logged in status after ajax/reload)

And there are many other files that might be the right one? How can I locate the right one? (same problem all the time :( )

Answer (score 0):

You do it in you `controller`, `action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"` is a controller **post url**, this url is set in your that module block.

When you post your form, the controller get that **form params** then it do some stuff and it **redirect** at the end, So you go to that controller then you change the url where you want to redirect after `fail` or `success`.

To get the controller url, you have to go the `block module` then you check `getPostActionUrl()`, or in console browser network (appear when submit a form).

#### Update :

1) 
The code :

```
if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectRoute) {
            $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($redirectRoute);
            $this->getAccountRedirect()->clearRedirectCookie();
        }
```

mean :

If you haven't set a value in admin config :  `customer/startup/redirect_dashboard`, it will redirect to the `$redirectRoute` Url.

2) Don't update `vendor/magento/module-customer/...`, you have to rewrite this controller or do an observer for that.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: @M2Newbie look my update

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know I should not edit core files, but I can not find where to edit. I have changed different files called Login.php, replacing URL's. Nothing works. Any guidance to which file I should edit?

Comment: did clean the cache ?

Comment: yes I cleaned cache etc. Usually I get an error, but here nothing. I doubt I am editing the right file.